# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')

Tags: python, ssl, homebrew

My company used homebrew to install any softwares.I recently installed python using homebrew and when try to run my existing framework seeing this error  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'). I don't see any python folder in my application foilder. I am using MacBook pro. Can someone suggest me how to install the local SSL certificates using homebrew. Any other solution for this issue?

This is how my brew config looks like

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.4.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: f7c7e2e793ed35f354974fb5fb22a3d924a3
Last commit: 11 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 9a696d92160083c82d504ebe7464b7f251
Core tap last commit: 4 days ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 12
all_proxy: 1
http_proxy:
https_proxy:
no_proxy: localhost,*.local, something related to office here
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1103
Git: 2.24.3 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 14.0.1
macOS: 10.15.5-x86_64
CLT: 11.4.0.1.1588476445
Xcode: N/A

Comment: There are lots of options for setting up certificates in the in the documentation for the [ssl module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html), for example [`SSLContextload_verify_locations()`](https://docs.python.org./3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations)

Comment: Can you attach your full `brew config` output?

Comment: sure, @chenuri I included  my brew config